# Maximizing healing and damage for a Cleric

Tags: feats, optimization, pathfinder-2e

I am planning this character out for levels 1-20. We're starting at level one and we are continuing until we're done or dead.

I'm having some trouble deciding on my feats, and spells to maximize damage and healing output.

I understand that warpriest clerics are given armor proficiency to help make creating a 2nd edition battle medic super easy, but I'm trying to balance my character perfectly between doing damage with my deity's weapon and healing my allies. I'm having a lot of trouble judging which trade-offs to take so that I can hit harder while still being a viable healer.

As a character, I've chosen Cleric, Warpriest, Dwarf, Medium Armror, Shelyn, and Glaive.

Right now, my plans for feats are leaning toward Domain initiate with Zeal, communal healing, divine weapon, but the details are starting to get fuzzy. It's all the different numbers floating around that are confusing. I really just want to increase the amount of healing from my spells and the amount of damage from my glaive. What is the best way to balance these two paths?

Comment: I'm failing to see a how this is a different question to the other one and so have voted to close as a duplicate. Don't worry, we don't hold grudges, but I will ask you not to try to get around closures by asking a new question (it just makes more work for everyone).

Comment: I tried to edit the question. But i can't tell how it will ever be reopened.

Comment: I also don't understand how there aren't enough details. Maximizing numbers is an absolute math.

Comment: Also, the suggestion said to create a new question. It straight up said to create a new one. I did exactly what the instructions said.

Comment: I can only advice to listen to the comments and editing the question to address those concerns (in as seamless a way as possible).